# Multiple App Sites

Tags: facebook, web, facebook-opengraph

In posting open graph actions we need to use URLs based on a different site than the one specified as Website in the App settings panel. We have an official site for our application and a "content site". At the moment we have specified the latter as the Mobile Site in the settings panel (it seems the only way to do that). Is there a more proper way to cope with such scenario?